# Open files with no extension

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx, file-extension

I have files without an extension type. I manually open them with Word before running a macro on them.

I created a second macro which opens all files within a folder then runs the other macro - which I can get working if the files have an extension.

Is there a way to get the second macro to open files without an extension as a Word doc? Or would there be another way of doing this?

Comment: Is it possible to fix this problem at the source? IOW: Why are you getting files with no extension?  Can that process be fixed so that the files *do* have an extension?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's the way the system creates them (sopra Mortgage and savings suite) which I have no control over. I think it's because they aren't actually docs they are just data files.

Comment: see if the solution I provided below will fix it for you

Comment: Yes that's fantastic, works thank you. I'm just trying to add my conversion macro to it now - where would I call it?

Comment: You could call this at the beginning of your other procedure, simply include the statement `Call assign_extension`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Fix the problem at the source. Wherever you're getting these files *from*, fix that so that the files will have an extension.

Option 2: Assign an extension:

```
Sub assign_extension()
Dim f
Dim FSO As Object
Const ext as String = ".txt"                       '### MODIFY AS NEEDED
Const path As String = "C:\Path\To Your Files\"    '### MODIFY AS NEEDED
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
f = Dir(path)
Do

    Debug.Print f
    If FSO.GetExtensionName(path & f) = vbNullString Then
        Name (path & f) As (path & f & ext)
    End If

    f = Dir()
Loop While f <> vbNullString

End Sub
```